# C++ error no matching function for call to ‘Nodo::Nodo(point&, float&, Nodo&)’

Tags: c++, lista, constructor, compilador, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Tengo un error en el código, precisamente en el constructor, el compilador dice que no le estoy pasando los parámetros adecuados, para poner en contexto, esta es la clase que tiene el constructor,solo pongo las funciones relevantes para entender la duda:

```
class Nodo {
private:
    point punto_;
    float coste_;
    Nodo* nodopadre_;

public:
    Nodo();
    Nodo(point& a, float coste,Nodo *nodopadre);
```

Este es el cpp

```
Nodo::Nodo(point& a, float& coste,Nodo *nodopadre):
    punto_(a),
    coste_(coste),
    nodopadre_(nodopadre){}
```

Donde surge el error del compilador, esto es en otra clase:

```
if((map.get(c_a,++c_b))!=1){

                point p(c_a,++c_b); 
                float costtan=0;
                list<Nodo>::iterator it1 = inspectioned_nodes_.end();
                it1--;
                Nodo np(*it1);
                Nodo ns(p,costtan,np); //ERROR
                costtan= g_n(ns)+ heuristica1(ns); //nodos adyacentes, distancia=1

                ns.set_coste(costtan);

                generated_nodes_.push(ns);
}
```

El error que me sale:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Nodo::Nodo(point&, float&, Nodo&)’
                 Nodo ns(p,costtan,np);
```

¿Tal vez será porque me falta sobrecargar el operador `=` en la clase `Nodo`?, aunque tengo un constructor de copia en esa clase.

`inspectioned_nodes_` es una lista de objetos `Nodo`

Se agradece ayuda. Gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El compilador se está quejando con toda la razón del mundo. Tu has declarado

```
Nodo( point& a, float coste, Nodo *nodopadre );
```

Sus argumentos son `referencia a point`, `copia de float`, `puntero a Nodo`. En el lugar en el que te marca el error, tenemos

```
Nodo np( *it1 );
Nodo ns( p, costtan, np ); //ERROR
```

1. Creas una nueva instancia de `Nodo`.
2. La pasas **por copia** o **por referencia**.

Simplemente, cambia tu línea a

```
Nodo ns( p, costtan, &np );
```

<sub>Por cierto, algo falla en tu lógica. Si lo haces así, estarás guardando un puntero a una variable automática ... que dejará de existir al salir de la función, y tendrás un puntero que apunta a ninguna parte ... ¿ No quedrás hacer `Nodo ns( p, costtan, &( *it1 ) )` ?</sub>

Answer (score 5):

> El error que me sale:
>
> ```
> error: no matching function for call to ‘Nodo::Nodo(point&, float&, Nodo&)’
>              Nodo ns(p,costtan,np);
> ```

El error que te sale es claro, conciso y autoexplicativo. Tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> ```
> error: ninguna función coincide para llamar a ‘Nodo::Nodo(point&, float&, Nodo&)’
> ```

Y te marca `Nodo ns(p,costtan,np);` como punto del error, esa instrucción parece ser una llamada al constructor de `Nodo` para crear una instancia llamada `ns`, vamos a ver los constructores de `Nodo`:

```
Nodo();
Nodo(point& a, float coste,Nodo *nodopadre);
```

La clase `Nodo` dispone de constructor por defecto y un constructor que recibe `point&`, `float` y `Nodo *` como argumentos, eso claramente no coincide con `point&`, `float&` y `Nodo&` que el compilador detecta ¿Por qué el compilador detecta esos tipos? Repasemos la instrucción conflictiva:

```
Nodo ns(p,costtan,np);
```

1. El primer argumento `p` se define así:

   ```
   point p(c_a,++c_b);
   ```
2. El segundo argumento `costtan` se define así:

   ```
   float costtan=0;
   ```
3. El tercer argumento `np` se define así:

   ```
   Nodo np(*it1);
   ```

Por lo tanto `p` es de tipo `point`, `costtan` es de tipo `float` y `np` es de tipo `Nodo`. Para coincidir con la firma del segundo constructor (`point&, float, Nodo *`), el primer argumento debe pasar por una conversión (a referencia) el segundo argumento no requiere conversión y **el tercer argumento no coincide con el tipo** (un `Nodo` no es un `Nodo *`) por lo que se descarta ese constructor.

Para solucionar el error, deberás pasar al constructor los tipos que espera.